# Syntax error near unexpected token 'done' in CygWin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I use this script in CygWin:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    rm -f nplist.txt
    find . -name "*.html"| while read file; do
        awk '
            /titleTable/ { if (NR==53) match1=1 }
            /id="maincontainer"/ { if (NR==169) match2=1 }
        { if (match1 && match2) exit 69 }
        ' file
        if test $? -eq 69; then
            echo $file
            sed -i '53,121d; 166,168d' $file
        else
        echo $file >>nplist.txt
       fi
    done
```

..and terminal tell me:

```
/cygdrive/c/1/test.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/cygdrive/c/1/test.sh: line 14: `done'
```

Why? Please, anybody help me!

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4.2.45 on Linux has no problem executing your script. Please check that the script text in the post matches your file. Check if there are any special characters in the file that get lost when transferring to the post text. Try simplifying your script, removing commands one by one and checking if it starts working.

Otherwise, I see one problem with your script: awk receives literal string `file` as the file to operate on, instead of `$file` variable value.